# How to fix error 'Traffic Control violation' when trying to POST to web API

Tags: node.js, post, postman

I'm trying to POST a small JSON to a webservice API. When I do this with Postman, I had to fetch the x-csrf-token and session cookie first. This was no problem. Then I could use these parameters to post the JSON to the API with Postman.
I'm trying to do the same thing using node.js . I fetched the node.js code snippet from Postman and included my x-csrf-token and session cookie. When I try to run it, it takes like 10 seconds and then I get a message saying "Traffic control violation" with a timestamp.

Does anyone know what this means?

I've already tried to refresh the cookies and the token. I just can't recall why it works through Postman with the same code.

```
 Traffic control violation
 Thu Aug 22 09:49:53 2019
```

Comment: **SOLUTION**  
I found the solution of the problem. The code snippet that I took from Postman included a 'Content-Length' parameter in the POST. This one is variable, it can change in my case so I just removed the 'Content-Length' parameter and that solved the problem.